# How to Fluently map with constraint in HasMany

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I’m new to (fluent) nHibernate.
I have 3 tables:
Agency
•   AgencyId (pk)
•   AgencyAccountNo

AgencyAccount
•   AgencyId (pk) (fk -> Agency. AgencyId)
•   AgencyAccountNo (pk)
•   ChainId (fk -> AgencyChain.ChainId)

AgencyChain
•   ChainId (pk)

AgencyAccount is effectively a versioning table. Everytime an Agency changes a new AgencyAccount row with an incremented AgencyAccountNo.

I am trying to fluently map the relationships in Agency and AgencyChain so that only the Current AgencyAccount will be returned, but have had a lot of trouble. I have tried many, many things, too numerous to go into here, and can’t seem to find any examples or documentation on this.

What would your approach be?

Comment: For anyone else who is interested; the join approach wont work as the AgencyAccount has a composite primary key, and exception is thrown:  
    Foreign key (FKF4659F6B49B309DE:AGENCY [AGENCY_NO])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (AGENCY_AC [AGENCY_NO, ACIN_NO])  
  
Using the where clause @Firo supplied in the HasMany does constrain the results though:  
    Where("AgencyAccountNo = (SELECT a.AgencyAccountNo FROM Agency a WHERE a.AgencyId = AgencyId)");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the normal/easy way Updated

```
class AgencyMap : ClassMap<Agency>
{
    public AgencyMap()
    {
        Id(a => a.Id);

        Map(a => a.AccountNo);
    }
}

class AgencyAccountMap : ClassMap<AgencyAccount>
{
    public AgencyAccountMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(aa => aa.Agency, "AgencyId")
            .KeyProperty(aa => aa.AccountNo, "AgencyAccountNo");

        References(a => a.Chain).Column("chainid");
    }
}

class AgencyChainMap : ClassMap<AgencyChain>
{
    public AgencyChainMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id);


        HasMany(c => c.AgencyAccounts)
            .KeyColumn("chainid")
            // to get only the actual AgencyAccounts
            .Where("AgencyAccountNo = (SELECT a.AgencyAccountNo FROM Agency a WHERE a.AgencyId = AgencyId)");

        // or if only interested in Agency (using a Set to prevent duplicates coming from the history of agencyaccounts)
        HasManyToMany(c => c.Agencys)
            .Table("AgencyAccount")
            .ParentKeyColumn("chainid")
            .ChildKeyColumn("agencyid")
            .AsSet();
    }
}

var account = session.Get<AgencyAccount>(new AgencyAccount { Agency = agency, AccountNo = agency.AccountNo });
```

the hackish way when not using Identity but some other id generation

```
class AgencyMap : ClassMap<Agency>
{
    public AgencyMap()
    {
        Table("AgencyAccount");
        Id(a => a.Id, "AgencyId").GeneratedBy.Sequence("agency_id_sequence"); // e.g. sequence

        Where("AgencyAccountNo = (SELECT a.AgencyAccountNo FROM Agency a WHERE a.AgencyId = AgencyId)");


        Map(a => a.AccountNo);

        Join("Agency", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("AgencyId");
            join.Map(<some other prop>);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:

- this makes inserting new AgencyAccounts for the same Account very difficult
- cant show the complete history of AgencyAccounts
- possibly has a lot of subtle problems

Comment: thanks for the answer. Re-reading my question I realise that I was less than clear, and I didn't go into enough detail, sorry.
I will mark this as answered and ask again.

Comment: perhaps I can just ask here: 
The first approach will not work when accessed via properties eg: Chain.AgencyAccounts, all will be selected.
The second approach will not work as the number of columns in the keys are diffrerent, and exception is thrown: : Foreign key (FKF4659F6B49B309DE:AGENCY [AGENCY_NO])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (AGENCY_AC [AGENCY_NO, ACIN_NO])

Comment: i did not know that chain has backreference to AgencyAccounts, will edit#

Comment: what do you mean the number of columns is not the same? there is only ever one keycolumn, where do you get the second keycolumn from?

Comment: The AgencyAccount table has a composite key (the two listed columns with (pk) after their names). This seems to make the join impossible. 
I was able to get the behaviour I need using the Where() clause you gave, so thanks.

Comment: I am trying to tackle a problem like yours and I am unable to use .Where("") did they remove that property? I need to map an entity to another entity with this configuration: e1.Id = e2.MasterAccountId (not the PK for the table) AND e2.IsMaster = TRUE. Having a hell of a time finding an answer for this. I would really appreciate your help Firo.

Comment: @SomeoneRandom i answered to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106785/fluent-nhibernate-multi-level-inheritance-based-on-another-column