# Fluent NHibernate's HasMany.Where overload method with lambda gives exception when referring child object property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

My fluent nHibernate mapping as follows

```
public class FilmMap : ClassMap<Film> 
{
    public FilmMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.FilmId, "film_id");
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.Title, "title");
        base.HasMany<FilmActor>(x => x.FilmChildActors).Where(x => x.Actor.Age < 16 ); 
    }
}

public class FilmActorMap : ClassMap<FilmActor>
{
    public FilmActorMap()
    {
        Table("film_actor");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ActorId, "actor_id")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.FilmId, "film_id");
        Map(x => x.LastUpdate, "last_update");
        References<Actor>(x => x.Actor, "actor_id").Fetch.Join();
    }
}

public class ActorMap : ClassMap<Actor>
{
    public ActorMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ActorId, "actor_id");
        Map(x => x.FirstName, "first_name");
        Map(x => x.LastName, "last_name");
        Map(x => x.Age, "Age");
      }
}
```

Getting the following exception at the time building the session factory

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=variable 'x' of type 'NhibernateTestProj.FilmActor' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()
       at FluentNHibernate.Utils.ExpressionToSql.Convert[T](Expression`1 expression, MemberExpression body) in D:\Renand\Download\jagregory-fluent-nhibernate-1.4.0.1-7-g65884f1\jagregory-fluent-nhibernate-65884f1\src\FluentNHibernate\Utils\ExpressionToSql.cs:line 54
  InnerException:
```

**Edit1: One more finding**

If I use

```
base.HasMany<FilmActor>(x => x.FilmChildActors).Where(x => x.ActorId = 16 );
```

then it adds the where condition in the sql as (filmactors.ActorId = 1), since ActorId is not there in the database it throws exception.

Please let me know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here `.Where(x => x.Actor.Age < 16 )` in the mapping

```
base.HasMany<FilmActor>(x => x.FilmChildActors).Where(x => x.Actor.Age < 16 );
```

This part is intended as a pure SQL Statement

```
.Where("SQL command") // or an boolean lambda expression
```

**We can work there only with the content of the table containing the collection data.** There is no way how to work with the `Actor.Age`... just with the `ActorId`.

But we can create a more complex SQL Statement, selecting those ActorIds, which are in some subselect

```
.Where("ActorId IN (SELECT a.ActorID FROM film_actor a ....
```

And in that case we can pass even some params like `WHERE a.actor_id = actor_id`, where the second `actor_id` is passed as param

For example check this QA [How to Fluently map with constraint in HasMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732508/how-to-fluently-map-with-constraint-in-hasmany)

Also check the [6.2. Mapping a Collection](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections), an extract:

> **`where=""`** *(optional)* specify an arbitrary SQL WHERE condition to be used when retrieving or removing the collection *(useful if the collection should contain only a subset of the available data)*

Comment: Great to see that! ;)